# Orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space $L^2(\left[0,+\infty\right[, dx)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am searching for an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space $L^2(\left[0,+\infty\right[, dx)$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you know about Fourier series?

Comment: [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Laguerre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials) $\{L_n\}$ are an orthogonal basis of the weighted space $L^2([0,\infty),e^{-x}\,dx)$. Then $\{e^{-x/2}L_n\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $L^2([0,\infty),dx)$.

Answer (score 4):

The change of variable $t=e^{-s}$ gives
$$
    \int_{0}^{1}f(t)g(t)dt = \int_0^\infty f(e^{-s})g(e^{-s})e^{-s} \, ds
$$
This may be interpreted as a unitary map $U : L^2[0,1)\rightarrow L^2[0,\infty)$ defined by
$$
             (Uf)(s) = e^{-s/2}f(e^{-s}).
$$
The transform is isometric, meaning that
$$
          \|f\|_{L^2[0,1)} = \|Uf\|_{L^2[0,\infty)}.
$$
And the change of variable is invertible, which proves that $U$ is unitary. Therefore, the unitary map $U$ maps orthonormal bases of $L^2[0,1)$ to orthonormal bases of $L^2[0,\infty)$. In particular,
$$
              \{ e^{-s/2}\exp(2\pi ine^{-s}) \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}
$$
is a complete orthonorml basis of $L^2[0,\infty)$.

Comment: This basis of $L^2[0,\infty)$ looks strange to me. It has high frequency content for small $s$ but not large $s$ unless you choose a gigantic rank $n$. If you have to approximate a solution of an ODE for instance, choosing the right truncated basis does not seem straightforward...